# Select values from a table, and put them in concrete/respective cells of another larger table, without losing lines of the latter

Tags: statistics, dataset

The below example which formulates my question, is only part of a very large dataset.

I have two different tables.
The first one has 13 rows and 3 columns

**Table 1**

```
SPA Code    UTM Cell Code   Conservation Grade
GR1110008   10kmE566N219    0
GR1110008   10kmE566N220    0 
GR1110008   10kmE566N221    0
GR1110008   10kmE567N219    0
GR1110008   10kmE567N220    0
GR1110008   10kmE567N221    0
GR1110008   10kmE568N220    0
GR1110008   10kmE568N221    0
GR1110008   10kmE569N219    0
GR1110008   10kmE569N220    0
GR1110008   10kmE570N217    0
GR1110008   10kmE570N218    0
GR1110008   10kmE570N219    0
```

The second table has 5 rows and 3 columns

**Table 2**

```
SPA Code    UTM Cell Code   Conservation Grade
GR1110008   10kmE566N220    B
GR1110008   10kmE566N221    A
GR1110008   10kmE567N219    A
GR1110008   10kmE567N221    B
GR1110008   10kmE569N220    A
```

The above tables actually represent the following:

- First column presents the national code of a Special Protected Area (SPAs of the Natura Network) for birds in Greece.
- The second column has the code of UTM (10x10km mapping grid) "geographical cells" that combine the SPA.
- The 3rd column is a coding describing each UTM cells' (of the second column) conservation grade in respect to wildlife.

In both tables the titles of the columns are the same. The difference is, that in the first table, the third column is completely null with no arithmetical values. Whereas, in the second table, the coding for conservation Grade is demonstrated, but many rows are missing, because only those rows with UTM cells that have an actual conservation grade are represented.

So now having described all the above, I come to my actual question:

How can I fill in, into Table 1, the Conservation Grade coding (e.g. A,B) that is demonstrated in 3rd column of Table 2 but for the same/respective UTM cell of column 2. In other words, I want to create a third table, which will have the same number of rows with Table 1, and identical 1st and 2nd column, but replacing the null values of the 3rd column with the values of 3rdcolumn/Table 2, for the respective UTM cells that have a Conservation Grade in Table 2.

Thank you very much, and sorry if my question was long

Answer (score 0):

An implementation in R is the following (assuming that the first matrix is `m` and the second `mm`):

```r
# logical vector that contains TRUE for all rows in m whose SPA code and UTM cell code do not exist in mm
rows <- apply(m, 1, function(x) length(mm[ mm[,1] == x[1] & mm[,2] == x[2] ,]) == 0)

# combine the filtered rows and mm
mat <- rbind(m[rows,], mm)

# sort the matrix
mat <- mat[order(mat[,1], mat[,2]),]
```

I'm an R newbie, so there might be a cleaner way to generate the `rows` vector that I'm not aware of.